# Image insertion problem, the output are some grey blocks

Tags: graphics, floats

[image]

What's wrong with my code? Thanks a lot for any help.

To prevent from any syntax error, I pasted all the codes below. The codes related to the image are at the bottom.

I compiled it with xelatex.

ps: I have made sure the correctness of the image.

Here are the codes:

```tex
%-- coding: UTF-8 --
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lastpage}%获得总页数
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}%首行缩进
\usepackage{amsmath}%aligned所需包
\newcommand{\ccr}[1]{\makecell{{\color{#1}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}}

\catcode`\^^I=12
%书签

%页面边距
\geometry{a4paper,left=2.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=2.7cm,bottom=2.7cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}%缩进2字符

%代码段设置
\lstset{
numbers=left,
basicstyle=\tiny,
numberstyle=\tiny,
keywordstyle=\color{blue!70},
commentstyle=\color{red!50!green!50!blue!50},
frame=single, rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
escapeinside=``
}
 
\renewcommand{\papertitle}{禀赋和跨时期选择}

% 页眉页脚
% \pagestyle{fancy}
% \lhead{\papertitle}
% \rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of\ \pageref{LastPage}}%当前页 of 总页数
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%改为0pt即可去掉页眉下面的横线
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%改为0pt即可去掉页脚上面的横线
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection{}.\arabic{figure}}%图片按章标号
\renewcommand{\figurename}{图}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{目录}           % 对Contents 进行汉化为目录

% 标题页设置
\title{\kaishu{\textbf{\papertitle}}}
\author{\kaishu{hello}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}


% 将上面定义的title加入到document中
\maketitle
\clearpage


\section{计算题}

\begin{figure}[!htb] %H为当前位置，!htb为忽略美学标准，htbp为浮动图形
    \centering %图片居中
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{images/1.jpg} %插入图片，[]中设置图片大小，{}中是图片文件名
\end{figure}


\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Maybe you can reduce your example code by removing both content and packages that are not related to your issue? This will make it easier to isolate the problem.

Comment: You could also try to use `\includegraphics{example-image}` instead of `\includegraphics{images/1.jpg}`. This should result in a dummy image that says "Image". If that works then there is a problem with your specific image, if it doesn't work then it's a problem with your code.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for your advise, I'll delete some code later . And I tried the example-image and other images, they are showed properly. But when I switch to my image, wrong again. Perhaps I'd change the image to solve this strange problem. Thanks again!

Comment: There could be an issue with the image, maybe it is not a jpg image (even though the name is `1.jpg`) but another format with a wrong name. Maybe the path or filename is incorrectly resolved, try renaming the image and put it in the same folder as the document (instead of in the `images/` folder). Maybe, although unlikely, there is a problem with jpg inclusion, you could try a different jpg image to test. Maybe it is a viewer problem and the output is correct with a different pdf viewer.